# Does instagram Like Button or follow Button return any value (PHP)?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to execute another function after user  follow someone or like a post.

Does instagram Follow Button or Like Button return any value like true or false. So I can perform any operation after ?

Or is there another alternative ??

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response of a successful response, according to the Instagram API Documentation (https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/#post_likes), should look like this.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "data": null
}
```

It doesn't really look like there is any data returned. However, you can use the built in AJAX Success callback like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your url here',
    data: 'your data here in the form of an object',
    //The success function will operate if the server compeletes is task,
    //or in this case, if the post is liked
    success: function(){

    }
});
```